# Flutter IOS, CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Analytics"

Tags: ios, firebase, flutter

This is an error, i do not use to get before. I got this after flutter 2.5 upgrade.

I have tried deleting Pods/, podfile.lock, repo update.

but still the error.

```
 [!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "Firebase/Analytics":
      In Podfile:
        firebase_analytics (from `.symlinks/plugins/firebase_analytics/ios`) was resolved to 8.3.4, which depends on
          Firebase/Analytics (= 8.8.0)
    None of your spec sources contain a spec satisfying the dependency: `Firebase/Analytics (= 8.8.0)`.
    You have either:
     * out-of-date source repos which you can update with `pod repo update` or with `pod install --repo-update`.
     * mistyped the name or version.
     * not added the source repo that hosts the Podspec to your Podfile.
```

Comment: Seems pretty straightforward; your pods are out of date. Quite possibly, your Cocoapods is out of date as well. You can check with `pod --version` and compare it to the current release version